# Use listeners with React useEffect hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an useEffect hooks that handle users online in my app

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState({} as Users);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleOnlineStatus = (onlineStatus: Array<OnlineStatus>) => {
    const usersCopy = {...users};
    if (onlineStatus.length === 0) {
        return;
    }


    onlineStatus.forEach((status: OnlineStatus) => {
        const uid = status.userId;

        if (!uid) {
        return;
        }

        if (uid in usersCopy) {
        const lastStatus = usersCopy[uid].status;
        if (lastStatus !== usersCopy) {
            usersCopy[uid].status = status.value;

            setUsers({...usersCopy});
        }
        }
    });
    };
    subscribeToIsOnline((onlineStatus: Array<OnlineStatus>) => {
        handleOnlineStatus(onlineStatus);
    });
});

public handleOnlineStatus(callback: (users: Array<OnlineStatus>) => void) {
    this.logDebug('subscribeToOnlineStatusIndication');

    try {
      return ChatClient.addListener('OnlineStatusIndication', (users: Array<OnlineStatus>) => callback(users));
    } catch (e) {
      this.logError(e);
    }
}
```

But using this code, the listener is re-created every time a user go back online.
So I updated the code like that :

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ... same code
}, []); // <--
```

But with this new code, setUsers never re-render the view.

How can I handle listeners with react hooks ?

Comment: Does `subscribeToIsOnline` return some cleanup function, like `unsubscribe`?

Comment: No it's a simple addListener, I updated the code

Comment: Ah bummer, it'd be easier if it did. We'll have to work around that then.

Comment: Maybe I can try to add one, the ChatClient is our code. Why is it important ? The subscriber should only instantiate one time right ?

Comment: Well, you've a stale enclosure of your `users` state, and if `subscribeToIsOnline` returned a cleanup function you could simply use `users` as the `useEffect` dependency and return the cleanup function to remove the listener when the `users` state updates. The other way involves splitting the handler out into it's own memoized callback or rewriting the logic so it uses a functional state update. The `uid in usersCopy` check kind of messes that up.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure I really understand how it should work, if you have time please right an answers, thank for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but you've enclosed your initial `users` state object (`{}`) in the callback. In other words it's a stale enclosure so you are always copying `users` state from the initial render.

You are also mutating state with `usersCopy[uid].status = status.value;`.

Use a functional state update to access the previous state from which you can update from.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState({} as Users);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleOnlineStatus = (onlineStatus: Array<OnlineStatus>) => {
    if (!onlineStatus.length) {
      return;
    }

    onlineStatus.forEach((status: OnlineStatus) => {
      const uid = status.userId;

      if (!uid) {
        return;
      }

      setUsers(users => {
        if (uid in users) {
          const lastStatus = users[uid].status;
          if (lastStatus !== users) {
            return {
              ...users, // <-- shallow copy into new state object
              [uid]: {
                ...users[uid], // <-- shallow copy old user object
                status: status.value, // <-- update property
              }
            };
          }
        }
        return users; // <-- old state
      });
    });
  };

  subscribeToIsOnline((onlineStatus: Array<OnlineStatus>) => {
    handleOnlineStatus(onlineStatus);
  });
}, []); // <-- empty dependency array to run effect once
```

Comment: Thank you Drew. Your code is working and most importantly I understand what was happening!